# what is the utility to a REST API for SIP trunk's?

Tags: web-applications, rest, api, automation, sip

Why does Twilio offer:

- Trunking REST API docs - Provision, configure, and modify SIP Trunks
  and phone numbers with the REST API.

What are the top usages for this API?  I appreciate that the process can be automated, but to what end?  Is it really so time consuming to click the buttons?  I'm having a fundamental difficulty in seeing much utility to this particular type of API in relation to SIP trunks.

Comment: There's a pretty good introduction here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/elastic-sip-trunking-api.html.  It describes the relevant use cases.

Comment: I asked the question here to solicit any personal experience with this type of API (not REST but this functionality) outside of twilio itself.  Yes, you're right, they give use cases, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having a fundamental difficulty in seeing much utility to this particular type of API in relation to SIP trunks.

Do you regularly manage telephone systems for large corporations with hundreds of lines and thousands of phone numbers?

If not that might be why you don't see the advantages of such a system :-)

> Is it really so time consuming to click the buttons?

Yes. Yes it is.

In the same way that it is time consuming to install, configure and deploy a server, which is why Amazon AWS is making a killing in the server market place providing a programmatic way to do this (Netflix deploy approx 10k servers in under a minute, run video conversion across all of the, and they pull them down again an hour later without anyone manually having to do anything).

It might not be time consuming to do it once at home to dial your mum, but that isn't the use case of Twillio. Twillio's customers include Walmart and Uber.

Why waste time doing something manually if it can be automated, particularly if it costs time and money for an employee to do it.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you wrote.  I was looking for a real-world concrete example, that's all.

Answer (score -1):

> I appreciate that the process can be automated

Yes. That's a huge thing, because …

> Is it really so time consuming to click the buttons?

… Programs can't click buttons.

You are essentially asking why programming would be useful. On a site for professional programmers, the sample population for your answers is probably going to be pretty biased ;-)

Comment: How many trunks are you setting up on a daily basis? I'm asking about this specific API, not REST or web API's in general.  Can you provide a concrete use case where this is an actual time saver?  A realistic usage for this **specific** API?

Comment: Resellers, SaaS providers, basically pretty much any relationship where the user of the trunking and the Twilio user are not one and the same.

Comment: @Thufir:  Twilio's entire business is providing APIs for these kinds of services, specifically so someone doesn't have to sit there and click the buttons.  Their marketing collateral is pretty much all use cases.

Comment: I was hoping someone would pipe up with "yes, I use it everyday.." but no worries.